# Android Studio: Exception breakpoints vs Java exception breakpoints

Tags: java, exception, android-studio, breakpoints

There are two types of exception breakpoints in Android Studio: Exception and Java exception.

It's obvious what triggers `Java exceptions breakpoints`, but I haven't figured out what would trigger the other `non-Java exception breakpoints`.

Any insight? Thanks.

[image: Android Studio breakpoint manager]

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I am asking what the usage is for the non-Java exception breakpoints.

Comment: well I wish I knew too.